# How can I "give" a forked process a diferent dynamic library than the one it "asks" for?

Tags: dynamic-linking, dynamic-loading

I want to know how I can "give" a forked process a different dynamic library than the one it "asks" for. For example, if the fork "asks" for the library "foo.so" the main process "intercepts" that and instead provides "bar.so".
Considering I don't know much about how dynamic libraries are loaded, it's very much possible that this is impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` for the forked process in `execve` pointing to a directory with your custom version of `foo.so`. More about shared libraries and environmental variables that control the loading process [here](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html).